# Accessing webkit-gradient property using Javascript

Tags: javascript, dom, webkit

I am trying to change the webkit-gradient property of a DIV section using Javascript. The user enters two colors for the gradient. Then when the user clicks a button, I want a DIV section to have a background showing the gradient with the two colors the user selected.

Thanks

Binu

Comment: Do you want to modify it for only an element or for the whole stylesheet?

Answer (score 0):

If you know how to put the gradient "control" strings together, you simply set the gradient expression up as the value of "backgroundImage" on the element's "style".

```
document.getElementById("yourDiv").style.backgroundImage = "-webkit-gradient(whatever)";
```

Of course the "whatever" part is a little complicated; probably you'd want something like:

```
var whatever = "linear, 0 0, 100 0, color-stop(0, " + color1 + "), color-stop(1, " + color2 + ")";

document.getElementById("yourDiv").style.backgroundImage = "-webkit-gradient(" + whatever + ")";
```

The line endpoints I just made up; exactly what you'd use depends on exactly how you want the gradient to look, and you should probably play with that yourself. [Here's a jsfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/5KqJ9/) (uses jQuery but just barely).

Answer (score 0):

working sample here: http://jsfiddle.net/ezmilhouse/4gbAW/

gradient calculations can become really big, check out http://gradients.glrzad.com/ for your inspiration.

your html:

```
<div id="gradient"></div>
<br/>
<br/>
<input type="text" value="#2446ab" id="color_1" />
<input type="text" value="#1867c8" id="color_2" />
<input type="button" value="Get Gradient!" />
```

your js:

```
$( 'input[type="button"]' ).live( 'click', function(){

    var col1 = $('#color_1').val();
    var col2 = $('#color_2').val();
    var css = '-webkit-gradient(linear,left bottom,left top, color-stop(0.30, ' + col1 + '),color-stop(0.50, ' + col2 + '))';

    $('#gradient').css('background-image', css);

});
```